# Can't serve HTML on the Google Apps Script callback page in a GMail add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons, gsuite-addons

I am working on a GMail add-on that connects to a third-party service through OAuth2. To obtain the authorization code the following redirect URI is used: *https://script.google.com/macros/d/[SCRIPT_ID]/usercallback* .
Here's a snippet that triggers authorization:

```
var stateToken = ScriptApp.newStateToken()
                          .withMethod( "authCallback" )
                          .withTimeout( 120 )
                          .createToken();

var authUrl = _authBaseUrl
              + "&client_id=" + encodeURIComponent( _clientId )
              + "&redirect_uri=" + encodeURIComponent( _redirectUri )
              + "&state=" + stateToken;

CardService.newAuthorizationException()
           .setAuthorizationUrl( authUrl )
           .setResourceDisplayName( "Resource" )
           .throwException();
```

And here's the callback function (the HTML snippet is taken from [here](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/non-google-services)):

```
function authCallback( request )
{
    createAccessToken( request.parameter.code );
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Success! <script>setTimeout(function() { top.window.close() }, 1);</script>');
}
```

The **createAccessToken** function gets successfully invoked and the add-on gets an access token. However, the HTML is not served in the popover window. Instead, there's a placeholder with the following error: *"The script completed but did not return anything."*

As a result, I am stuck with an error window which can't be closed automatically and doesn't tell user that they have to close the window to continue working with the add-on.

Is there anything wrong I am doing or this is some kind of bug or a dropped feature? Thanks for any suggestions.

UPD: 
The error looks like this[image]

Comment: Don't Gmail add-ons need to return Cards?

Comment: @tehhowch you have to return Cards to the add-on itself but you can't return them to browser windows opened through OpenLink or AuthorizationException.

Comment: Have you tried `ContentService` instead of html?

Comment: @TheMaster yes, I tried both `return ContentService.createTextOutput("Success!");` and some JS with respective mime type in authCallback and doGet. The result is the same.

Comment: If you have a `doGet()` returning from contentService, Have you published the script as a web app?

Comment: @TheMaster nope, it was just a desperate attempt to make it work.

Comment: If you do publish, you need to save , create a new version after every change to the script

Comment: The callback function for OAuth2 flows don't require a doGet(e) or a web app to be published.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the HtmlService actually works in that case. I had a function name collision for **authCallback**, so the proper one wasn't invoked. Sorry for misinformation. If anyone has trouble handling the callback window, do as described in the question.